# Openttd: Why do I have a poor station rating for an industry that has closed?

Tags: openttd

I have station built near a city and it was happily transporting passengers, mail, and iron ore. A while back, the iron ore mine shut down and disappeared from the map. I sold off the train hauling the iron ore after making sure I transported the last ton out of the station. 
Recently, I checked my station rating for transport services and noticed that while I'm doing fine on passengers and mail, there is still a rating for Iron Ore: Very Poor (22%).

Why, if there is no longer any trains servicing that industry type, no quantity of that type of commodity 'waiting' and no longer any industry within the station catchment area, does it still show on my station rating?

I just didn't want a poor rating to affect my overall station rating and my local authority rating with the town.

Comment: Why not ask on openTTD though? Maybe it's a bug, and they would be happy to get your input...

Comment: Did you pick all the iron ore before selling the train?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately when an industry closes you will still get the rating at that station for all time.  The good news is that the station rating doesn't affect your standing with the local authority<sup>[ref](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Game%20Mechanics/#local-authority-rating)</sup> and all it does is affect the volume of cargo you receive from that industry. Given the industry is no longer there, it doesn't affect anything other than your ego!

There are two ways out of it:

1. Fund a new industry near the station
2. Demolish the station and rebuild it (when the name has reset). You'll have to re-route all your trains, however.